# Laravel and Vuejs 3 Image updating not working

Tags: laravel, image, axios, controller, vuejs3

I managed to create a post with image and now I want to be able to update it too. Everything was working fine with the update method when i upload new image and try to update i got old image new iamge isn't updating. Bellow my code:

```
<form @submit.prevent="UpdateService" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="mb-4">
                <label class="form-label" for="image">Upload Image</label>
                <input type="file" name="image" @change="onChangeServiceUpdateImage" class="form-control"/>
                <img :src="ServiceUpdateForm.url" class="img-fluid mt-2" width="100" />
                <HasError :form="ServiceUpdateForm" field="image" />
            </div>
</form>
```

VueComponenet.vue

```
 export default {
    data: () => ({
        ServiceUpdateForm: new Form({
            name: "",
            status: "",
            desc: "",
            icon_class: "",
            image: "",
            url: "",
            _method: "put",
        }),
        editor: ClassicEditor,
        editorConfig: {},
        language: 'en',
    }),
    methods: {
         onChangeServiceUpdateImage(e){
          // console.log(e.target.files[0]);
          const file = e.target.files[0];
          this.ServiceUpdateForm.url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
          this.ServiceUpdateForm.image = file;
        },
        async UpdateService() {
            let slug = this.$route.params.slug;

            $api.post(`/service/${slug}`, this.ServiceUpdateForm).then(() => {

                this.$router.push({ name: "backend-service-manage" });
                Toast.fire({
                  icon: 'success',
                  title: 'Data Update Successful!'
                })
                
            }).catch(error => {
                Toast.fire({
                  icon: 'error',
                  title: 'Data is missing!'
                })
            });
        },
    }
```

Controller

```
 if($request->hasFile('image')){
            // Delete Existing Image
            if( File::exists('frontend/assets/img/service/' . $service->image) ) {
                File::delete('frontend/assets/img/service/' . $service->image);
            }
            $logo = time().'.'.request()->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $request->selectedfile->move(public_path('frontend/assets/img/service'), $logo);
            $service->image = $logo;
        }

        $service->save();

        return response()->json('success', 200);
```

Comment: Can you log the input values in controller?

Comment: yes I can and also tested the image field came empty